# Where would I report missing metadata in Crossref / Science?

Tags: publications, citations, journals

I hope this isn't the wrong part of the StackExchange network to ask this; if so, please point me in the right direction :-)

I just stumbled across missing metadata in Crossref, where the initial experimental publication on Graphene ([DOI link](http://dx.doi.org/10.1126/science.1102896)) shows only the first author (Novoselov) in [Crossref's metadata](https://search.crossref.org/?q=10.1126%2Fscience.1102896), rather than the eight authors on the actual publication.

As I couldn't quickly find something like a "report error" link - does anyone know where one would *generally* report such an omission? Should one rather address Crossref or the "data provider" (in this case: Science)?

**Update, after [Anyon](https://academia.stackexchange.com/users/17254/anyon) pointed me in the right direction :**

As it turns out, there is a [list of all depositors](https://www.crossref.org/06members/51depositor.html) (which takes *forever* to load), from where one can get details for all publications controlled by a specific depositor; turns out that [URL scheme](https://apps.crossref.org/myCrossref/?report=missingmetadata&datatype=j&prefix=10.1126) includes the prefix of the DOI:

`https://apps.crossref.org/myCrossref/?report=missingmetadata&datatype=j&prefix=10.1126`<— right here

which makes it easer to go directly to the "Missing Metadata Report" page. This then seems to indicate that 62,901 out of 265,942 articles (i.e. nearly 25%!) from Science are apparently missing author information (if I'm reading this correct), so *no big deal, I guess??*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Crossref's FAQ](https://www.crossref.org/faqs/#q6general):

> I’ve found a problem within your metadata - how do I get you to fix it?
>
> While we aren’t able to correct the metadata provided by our members, report any metadata issues to our [support staff](https://support.crossref.org/hc/en-us/requests/new) and we’ll contact the responsible member and ask them to make corrections.

Comment: How on earth did I *not find this*.. :-D

Comment: @Asmus Maybe Crossref is to blame for making the "search" and "www" subdomains so disjoint...

Comment: I've also now found a "Missing Metadata Report" page for Science, see the updated question.